# Swipe to delete moves the UITableViewCell to the left

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swipe

I use custom code to create cells that get displayed on a UITableView. When a row is swiped, the delete button appears on the far right of the cell as expected. However it causes the contents of the cell to move to the left (partly off screen). This kind of behaviour didn't happen when using the cells that are built in to the framework.

Comment: Please post the code in which you set up your table view cells. There’s a couple of things that could cause this, but without seeing the code any answer would be guesswork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UIView` property `autoresizingMask` allows you to specify how your subviews should behave when their superview (in this case the `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`) gets resized.

See the [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW15) for more information.

Comment: thanks jlehr, you nailed it. I changed the autoresizingMask to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin and it worked. Many thanks

Comment: @fidel you changed the autoresizingMask of what exactly? I can't get it to work

Comment: Hi xaphod, it was a long time ago so I don't remember, but I assume it was the UIView

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it because your content is bound to the right edge?

Comment: thanks Panos, yep it was to do with the autoresizingMask property of the labels on the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer may be too late, I believe the problem is due to the fact that you happen to be adding your content directly to the cell by writing something like:

```
MyView* myView = [[MyView alloc] init];
[cell addSubview : myView];
```

This happens to be good; however, your content will be affected by any change that takes place within the cell.  If, on the other hand, you want your views to remain intact while anything else happens to the cell, you must add your content as subviews of the cell's contentView:

```
MyView* myView = [[MyView alloc] init];
[[cell contentView] addSubview : myView];
```

I do hope this helps.

Cheers!